# Outlook rules: how to recognize a group as sender and not its members?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange

In my organization, we use Office 365.

I receive payrolls and sometimes announcement from an HR mailing list `ACME Staff <staff@acme.com>`. This mailbox is mapped to a group whose members are not only HR staff, but also the CEO and the director of IT (to whom I might ask the question directly).

The payrolls are likely sent by a deamon software, logging in to Outlook as `staff@acme.com`. There are in fact no traces of the original sender.

Anyway, I have tried to set an automatic rule so that all emails coming from `ACME Staff` are redirected to a custom folder, where I archive payrolls and important labour-related updates.

However, this has the side effect, documented with a warning from Outlook, that all emails coming from the members of the group will be redirected.

This has a side effect. Since the CEO is my direct boss, when I invite them to a meeting, I get their RSVP into the "Labour" folder. This tricks me into thinking that an important announcement was delivered, but it's not the case.

Also, when I write the HR manager, I don't want their emails necessarily go into the "Labour" folder.

What I want is that emails that are "From: ACME Staff" and not "from a member of such group" to be redirected.

How do I achieve that in Outlook 365? For clarity, I mean the Windows client

Answer (score 1):

You could try "with XXX in the message header" and see if it works.Replace XXX with ACME Staff (the HR mailing list name with email address)

Comment: This would catch emails sent *to* the DL as well as those sent *from* the DL

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the rule condition "from **people or public group**", try the condition "with **specific words** in the sender's address" and give staff@acme.com as the specific word.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution doesn’t work - adding the DL name or the DL email address doesn’t match